# Show a matrix in detail

Tags: matrices

Below it is a very useful command to create a matrix. But it has a short point to me since it shows Parentheses not Square brackets. My question it how should I change this to show square brackets? I appreciate your answer. Thank you so much.

```
\[
K =
  \underbracket{\begin{pmatrix}
   K_1 & 0      & 0    \\
   0   & \ddots &    0   \\
   0   & 0      & K_n    \\
   \end{pmatrix}}_{d\times M}
\]
```

Comment: `\begin{bmatrix}`?

Comment: replace `{pmatrix}` with `{bmatrix}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to replace parentheses around a matrix by square brackets, replace `{pmatrix}` with `{bmatrix}`.

this requires `amsmath`, but once you've done that, you also have

- `Bmatrix` -- curly braces
- `vmatrix` -- single vertical bars
- `Vmatrix` -- double vertical bars

the left and right delimiters are properly spaced for the left and right positions, a
nicety that isn't always automatic.